# how to use fortawesome in typescript file?

Tags: angular, typescript, font-awesome

I'm using fortawesome for font-awesome in order to load only used icons.

All icons used are declared in app.module.ts.

```
import { FontAwesomeModule, FaIconLibrary } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import {
    faSignOutAlt, faUser, faCog, faAlignLeft,
    faWarehouse, faVectorSquare, faTh, faArrowAltCircleDown,
    faArrowAltCircleLeft,faArrowAltCircleRight,faArrowAltCircleUp
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faMap, faTrashAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
...
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private _library: FaIconLibrary) {
      _library.addIcons(faCog, faUser, faAlignLeft,
        faWarehouse, faVectorSquare, faSignOutAlt,
        faMap, faTrashAlt, faTh ,
        faArrowAltCircleDown, faArrowAltCircleLeft,faArrowAltCircleRight,
        faArrowAltCircleUp);
  }
```

it works fine in template

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'align-left']"></fa-icon>
```

but how do you do when you want to use it in the component class?
I want to use en primeng select button menu in my template like that:

```
<p-selectButton [options]="directions" [(ngModel)]="sens"></p-selectButton>

this.directions = [
  {label: '', value: 'd', icon: 'fas fa-arrow-circle-right'},
  {label: '', value: 'b', icon: 'fas fa-arrow-circle-down'},
  {label: '', value: 'h', icon: 'fas fa-arrow-circle-up'},
  {label: '', value: 'g', icon: 'fas fa-arrow-circle-left'}
];
```

the result is:
[image]

what am i supposed to use instead of 'fas fa-arrow-circle-right' to have it working or it is meant to be used them only in templates?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this ?

Comment: When you create the kit, use the option to create the web-font one and not the svg one. https://blog.fontawesome.com/webfont-vs-svg/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import {faSignOutAlt as fasSignOutAlt, 
        faUser as fasUser, 
        faCog as fasCog, 
        faAlignLeft as fasAlignLeft,
        ...
       } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'; //<-- as fas[ICON] when free-solid

import { faMap as farMap, 
         faTrashAlt as farTrashAlt
       } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'; //<-- as far[ICON] when free-regular

...

constructor(_library: FaIconLibrary) {
    library.addIconPacks(fas)
    _library.addIcons(fasSignOutAlt, fasUser, fasCog, fasAlignLeft,...
                      farMap,farTrashAlt,...) 
}
```

In .html

```
<!--see that you use kebab case, (the '-' to separate word)-->
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'sign-out-alt']"></fa-icon>
<fa-icon [icon]="['far', 'trash-alt']"></fa-icon>
```